# R: transposing and splitting a row with a delimiter.

Tags: r, reshape, transpose

I have a table

```
rawData <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,"a,b,c","d,e","f"),nrow=3,ncol=3))

 1  4 a,b,c
 2  5   d,e
 3  6     f
```

I would like to convert to

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
a  d  f
b  e
c
```

so far I can transpose and split the third column, however, I'm lost as to how to reconstruct a new table with the format outline above?

```
new = t(rawData)

for (e in 1:ncol(new)){
  s<-strsplit(new[3:3,e], split=",")
  print(s)
}
```

I tried creating new vectors for each iteration but I'm not sure how to efficiently put each one back into a dataframe.  Would be grateful for any help. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `stri_list2matrix` from the `stringi` package:

```
library(stringi)       
rawData <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,"a,b,c","d,e","f"),nrow=3,ncol=3),stringsAsFactors = F)

d1 <- t(rawData[,1:2])
rownames(d1) <- NULL

d2 <- stri_list2matrix(strsplit(rawData$V3,split=','))

rbind(d1,d2)  
#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "1"  "2"  "3" 
# [2,] "4"  "5"  "6" 
# [3,] "a"  "d"  "f" 
# [4,] "b"  "e"  NA  
# [5,] "c"  NA   NA
```

Comment: Something like `plyr::rbind.fill`

Comment: One-liner `rbind(
    unname(t(rawData[-3])), 
    stri_split_fixed(rawData$V3, ",", simplify="array")
)` :-)

Comment: thanks, this is clever, and totally works! Makes sense to my newbie skills ;)

Comment: In regard to my last, from the docs it should be `simplify=NA`, not `"array"`.  Not sure why "array" works

Comment: @RichardScriven, `simplify="array"` does not work for me

Comment: @MaratTalipov - What `stringi` version?  I'm on 0.4.1

Comment: @RichardScriven, I had an older version. I've updated `stringi`, and now `simplify="array"` works for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package.

By default, it just creates additional columns after splitting the input:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(rawData, "V3")
#    V1 V2 V3_1 V3_2 V3_3
# 1:  1  4    a    b    c
# 2:  2  5    d    e   NA
# 3:  3  6    f   NA   NA
```

You can just transpose that to get your desired output.

```
t(cSplit(rawData, "V3"))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# V1   "1"  "2"  "3" 
# V2   "4"  "5"  "6" 
# V3_1 "a"  "d"  "f" 
# V3_2 "b"  "e"  NA  
# V3_3 "c"  NA   NA
```

Comment: Maybe add `t` as attitudinal parameter to `cSplit`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, feature bloat? (I also don't know why anyone would want their data in this form, which is why I left the original output too (which would actually still be in a usable form...)

Comment: I guess its like `stri_list2matrix` `byrow` parameter?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, that's a little bit different because it's operating on a single input vector that can be independent of a `data.frame` whereas `cSplit` is specifically to split up columns in a `data.frame`.